# PHP Add Updated Array to Current Session

Tags: php, arrays, session

Ok, so my aim is to add the current profile id ($for) to my session, the aim is for the system to understand which profiles have been viewed in the current session, thus adding to the array. Then it will check the array if it exists and will not show a popup on load as this only needs to happen once.

```
$for = $_GET['id'];

//GET PREVIOUSLY VIEWED IDS
$prevViewed = $_SESSION['viewedID'];

//THEN ADD THIS PAGE ID TO PREVIOUSLY VIEWED ARRAY
$prevViewed = $for;

//UPDATE SESSION WITH NEW ARRAY INC CURRENT PAGE
$_SESSION['viewedID'] = $prevViewed;

print_r($_SESSION['viewedID']);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
// Make sure that SESSION has the viewedID array
if (!isset($_SESSION['viewedID'])) $_SESSION['viewedID'] = array();

// Store this page in the array
$_SESSION['viewedID'][$for] = true;
```

You can then check if this page has been viewed with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['viewedID'][$for]))
// it has been viewed
else
// it hasn't
```

Answer (score 0):

I like it, looks like it would work a dream. However, I have fixed it now:

Add to Array the Profile which HAS been viewed...

```
//ADD THIS PAGE ID TO PREVIOUSLY VIEWED ARRAY
$prevViewed = $for;

//UPDATE SESSION WITH NEW ARRAY INC CURRENT PAGE
$_SESSION['viewedID'][] = $prevViewed;
```

Check the array for the Current Profile ID...

```
//CHECK IF CURRENT ID IS NOT IN ARRAY
if(isset($_SESSION['viewedID'])) {

    if (!in_array($for, $_SESSION['viewedID'])) { 
      //PERFORM ACTION IF NOT IN ARRAY
    } else {
      //PERFORM ACTION IF IS IN ARRAY
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone.